# How to fix can not resolve symbol OnMenuTabClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-bottomnav, bottombar

I am creating a `BottomBar` menu, but  i'm getting an error on `OnMenuTabClickListener` when i try to import `com.roughike.bottombar.OnMenuTabClickListener`, which says that `OnMenuTabClickListener` 'cannot resolve the symbol'. Another error is in the following lines of code where you also get 'cannot resolve the symbol' :

```
mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
    mBottomBar.setItems(R.menu.bottombar_menu);
    mBottomBar.setOnMenuTabClickListener(new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
  ....
```

**My build.gradle :**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "faster.app.name.kga"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), '     proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
  compile 'com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:1.0.3'
  compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.3.9'
```

Comment: maybe try a newer version of bottombar - 2.1.1 is current yet you are using 1.3.9

Comment: Well, it exists... https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/blob/v1/bottom-bar/src/main/java/com/roughike/bottombar/OnMenuTabClickListener.java

Comment: @StellBytes What is the up to date version of  bottombar library  ? i used 2.1.1 but it does not work